Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get URL /post/slug from this server
After deploying my nextjs app directory which contains dynamic pages, by enabling firebase frameworks, the app is deployed successfully and firebase creates a ssr function to generate dynamic routes. when i tried to get my first dynamic page, this error was triggered: Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get the URL /post from this server.
As mentioned in GCP community posts, I tried to get full access to SSR function for all users by adding a new role: AllUsers and assigning a cloud function invoker, but it doesn't work. I cleared all caches and used other incognito browsers.

RESOLVED!
After many attempts, I finally got this magic solution:
1- go to this link : https://console.cloud.google.com/run?referrer=search&authuser=0&hl=en&project=[YOUR-PROJECT-NAME]
2- Check the box corresponding to your ssr function.
3- click on 'permissions' and add principal
4-Type AllUsers and select
5-find role : CLOUD RUN INVOKER
6- click on validate: and that's it, good luck.
